# Spring Data JPA - Specifiaction

Tags: sql, spring, spring-data-jpa, specifications

I have a SQL native query. I want to convert it into Specification object so that I can pass additional conditions and Pageable object with it.

```
select * from tableA where (colA, colB) in
    (select colA, min(colB) from tableA
        group by colA
     )
```

I want to implement a subquery, min function.

Also, can someone suggest where can I find proper documentation for these spring data JPA specification?

Comment: Please check [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#specifications)

Comment: I am not able to find the solution for my problem in the documentation .

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to have subquery in the select clause in JPQL query.

You can use WHERE and HAVING clausesalong with  ANY, SOME, ALL, IN, EXIST expressions

```
SELECT a
FROM A a
WHERE a.val = (SELECT b.someval 
               FROM B b 
               WHERE b.someotherval=3)
```